# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{5x+1}{(2x+1)(x-1)}dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int\frac{5x+1}{(2x+1)(x-1)}dx$$

$$\frac{A}{(2x+1)}+\frac{B}{(x-1)}$$

$$\frac{A(x-1)+B(2x-1)}{(2x+1)(x-1)}$$

I put $x=1$ to attain B: $5\ (1)+1=A(1-1)+B\ (2(1)+1)$

$$6=0+3B$$

$$B=2$$

However, I am unable to utilize the same method to attain A.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You had a mistake in your computations. See the first line below. You have written $B(2x-1)$ instead of $B(2x+1)$.

Consider the following steps

$$\eqalign{
  & {{5x + 1} \over {(2x + 1)(x - 1)}} = {A \over {2x + 1}} + {B \over {x - 1}} = {{A\left( {x - 1} \right) + B\left( {2x + 1} \right)} \over {(2x + 1)(x - 1)}}  \cr 
  & 5x + 1 = A\left( {x - 1} \right) + B\left( {2x + 1} \right)  \cr 
  & x = 1\,\,\, \to \,\,\,6 = 3B\,\,\, \to \,\,\,B = 2  \cr 
  & x =  - {1 \over 2}\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\, - {3 \over 2} =  - {3 \over 2}A\,\,\, \to \,\,\,A = 1  \cr 
  & {{5x + 1} \over {(2x + 1)(x - 1)}} = {1 \over {2x + 1}} + {2 \over {x - 1}} \cr} $$

Comment: Thus the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+1|+2\ln|x-1|+C$

Comment: @Cetshwayo: Yes! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ instead to attain $A$.

By the way, your numerator on $x - 1$ is incorrect. It should be $2x +1$ instead of $2x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also compare coefficients on both sides. For example, here, once you've found B, look at the constant term on both sides:
$$1=-A+B $$
Since $B=2$, we see that $A=1$.